# Renaming files according to fasta header

Tags: python, file-rename, fasta

I have downloaded 240 genomes from NCBI and when downloaded they get a filename according to their assembly numbers. I would like to rename the files according to their species name, instead of their assembly numbers, as this will make interpretation of the data much easier.

I know some (very little) python, and I haven't really been able to google myself out of the problem.

So what I would like to do is to write a loop that goes into each file in my folder and rewrites the file name according to the fasta header

Example of filename: GCF_000014225.1_ASM1422v1_genomic.fna

Example of fasta header: >NC_008228.1 Pseudoalteromonas atlantica T6c, complete genome

Obviously I would be happy if I could ret rid of the NC_008228.1 and, complete genome, but just the fasta header as filename would make my life much easier (alternative is doing it manually...but I know it can be done with some coding)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably do-able using `sys` but I think `bash` is a better answer to your problem. Something like:

```
for file in /dir/*; do
header=$(cat $file | egrep ">.*\w([a-zA-z]\w[a-zA-z])\w.*)")
mv $file $header.fa
done
```